# Unable to Authenticate User in Vue.js App Using Fetch Wrapper and Laravel API - 405 Method Not Allowed Error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, cors, fetch-api

*Description*
I'm encountering an issue with user authentication in my Vue.js application that communicates with a Laravel backend through an API. When attempting to log in, I receive a **405 Method Not Allowed error**. The error message indicates that the server returned a "**Method Not Allowed**" response.

*Steps Taken:*

1. My Vue.js app utilizes a fetch wrapper method to interact with the Laravel API.
2. The fetch wrapper method is structured to handle authentication headers and response parsing.
3. The specific error occurs when making a POST request to the /api/login endpoint.

*Here's a snippet of my fetch wrapper method:*

```
export const fetchWrapper = {
    get: request('GET'),
    post: request('POST'),
    put: request('PUT'),
    delete: request('DELETE')
};

function request(method) {
    return (url, body) => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method,
            headers: authHeader(url)
        };
        if (body) {
            requestOptions.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
            requestOptions.body = JSON.stringify(body);
        }
        return fetch(url, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
    }
}

function authHeader(url) {
    // ... (authentication header implementation)
    // return auth header with jwt if user is logged in and request is to the api url
    const { token } = useAuthStore();
    const isLoggedIn = !!token;
    const isApiUrl = url.startsWith(//path_to_env->api_url);
    if (isLoggedIn && isApiUrl) {
        return { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` };
    } else {
        return {};
    }

}

function handleResponse(response) {
    // ... (handle response implementation)
    return response.text().then(text => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            const { user, logout } = useAuthStore();
            if ([401, 403].includes(response.status) && user) {
                // auto logout if 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden response returned from api
                logout();
            }

            const error = (text && text) || response.statusText;
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        try {
            const data = JSON.parse(text);
            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            // Handle parsing error for non-JSON response
            console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
            return text;
        }
    });
}
```

*And here's where I use the fetch wrapper to perform a login:*

```
async login(username, password) {
    try {
        const res = await fetchWrapper.post(`${url}/login`, {
            email: username,
            password: password,
        }, {
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });

        // ... (login response handling)
    } catch (error) {
        // ... (fetch error handling)
    }
}
```

*Issue:*
Despite the correct headers being set, the API responds with a 405 Method Not Allowed error. I've ensured that the server allows the POST method for the /api/login endpoint.

Additional Information:

Laravel version: Laravel Installer 5.2.1
Vue.js version: @vue/cli 5.0.8
CORS configuration in Laravel:

```
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

network configurations: LocalHost

- Checked CORS Configuration: Ensure that the CORS configuration on the Laravel backend allows the POST method for the /api/login endpoint. I've verified that the allowed_methods in the CORS configuration include 'POST'.
- 
- Verified Endpoint Availability: Confirm that the /api/login endpoint is available and intended to handle POST requests on the Laravel backend.
- 
- Review of Fetch Wrapper Implementation: Double-checked the implementation of the fetch wrapper method to make sure that the POST request is being constructed correctly with the required headers.

*I was expecting *

1. Successful Authentication: I expected that making a POST request to the /api/login endpoint with valid credentials would result in successful authentication, returning a token that could be used for subsequent requests.
2. No Method Not Allowed Error: I anticipated that there would be no "Method Not Allowed" error since the CORS configuration and route definition should allow POST requests.

Comment: go to your network tab from the browser and check what the method your request is using

Comment: The error means the route you're trying to hit is not available for the requested method. Would be good to see the `api.php` snippet from Laravel.

Comment: ok i will check that

Comment: In the network tab the method was 'POST'

Comment: Here is the code in my api.php `<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController;

Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');


//Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    //return $request->user();
//});
` any feedback

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.